# How to set Driver Distraction Optimize for Expo React Native project

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

I am building an app to run in a truck side screen, and I want to allow the users to use it while driving. I have tried many ways and nothing really works. One of my current solution was creating an expo plugin and adding `<meta-data android:name="distractionOptimized" android:value="true"/>`  to AndroidManifest file. You can find the native code below. When I built it locally, I kept getting same error:

> Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
> Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
> This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

If someone has a solution, please share. I would appreciate that a lot.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
 <meta-data android:name="distractionOptimized" android:value="true"/>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="diffo"/>
    <data android:scheme="com.name.my_app"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```